# Is it possible to draw a rectangle without using the paintComponent or paint method?

Tags: java, graphics, paint, paintcomponent

It's not working if I just declare Graphics g and type in g.drawRect in my code. I hope there's another alternative though. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Framework? Sorry, I'm just a beginner D:

Comment: I mean programming language and environment you use. The tags added to your question make it clear now.

Answer (score 0):

A Graphics Object must be attached to some bits, either gotten from some GUI component, or a BufferedImage. It doesn't make sense to just allocate a Graphics object and draw into it.

So it would probably help if you showed what you were doing (or wanted to do)

Comment: I just want to draw a rectangle over my bufferedimage, but my paintcomponent is not repainting.

Comment: A BufferedImage isn't displayed by default, it's just an in memory bitmap. After you draw into your BufferedImage if you want to display it then you would need to use g.drawImage using that bufferedImage, into another GraphicsObject that is tied to some gui component. Since you are drawing on screen, you would need to do that inside a paintComponent call.

Comment: Yeah. I did that. Didn't work. Or do you mean I put my bufferedimage inside my Graphics?